# definition of limits and continuity in complex analysis

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity

Here is the definition my textbook gives:

[image]

Suppose a have a function $f$ with domain $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le 1\}$. The point $i$ has $|i|=1$ and is in $f$'s domain. $f$ is not defined on any deleted neighborhood of $i$. Does this mean $\lim_{z \to i} f(z)$ does not exist?

My textbook gives this definition for continuity:

[image]

Does this mean $f$ is not continuous at $i$ because $\lim_{z \to i} f(z)$ does not exist?

Comment: According to those definitions you presented, you are correct. However, those are not the standard definitions. The standard definition of limit only requires that every disk around $x_0$ contains a point in the domain of $f$ not equal to $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f:D\subset \Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$  and $z_0\in \Bbb{C}$ be a limit point of $D$ . Then $$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) =L$$ if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\color{red}{\forall z\in D}$ with $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(z) -L|<\epsilon$

In other words, we are not interested on all points of the deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ ,we are interested on all those points in deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ which are inside the domain $D$ $( $such points are always exists as $z_0$ is a limit point of $D) $